# storing facebook session from javascript to php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to store the session got from javascript to PHP's session? I know that I have to do a POST, can someone give me an example? This is what I have so far: I want to store the uid in PHP's session

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    FB.init({appId: '135570939849404', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                         //do smething?
                     }else {
                        window.location = "index.php"
                     }       
                    });


                });
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried the [Facebook PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)? it will take care of this for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently you know what you want to do, so using Jquery's ajax methods. There you can enable the post method.

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
  async:true, 
  type: "POST", 
  url: ("/yourTarget.php"), 
    dataType : 'json',

    data: {email : 'Jeremy'},

    success : function(data){

        alert("success");

    },

    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The uid is stored in the FB object as response.session.uid, which is the parameter you need to send via Ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                FB.init({appId: '135570939849404', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.session) {
                     jQuery.ajax({ 
                                async:true, 
                                type: "POST", 
                                url: ("/yourTarget.php"), 
                                dataType : 'json',
                                data: {uid : response.session.uid},
                                success : function(data){
                                    alert("success");
                                },
                                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert("error");
                                }

                        });

                 }else {
                    window.location = "index.php"
                 }       
                });


            });
    </script>
```

The session data is all stored on a cookie that you read in javaScript. You can of course access this data directly from PHP if you want using something like this code:

```
function get_facebook_session_data($app_id, $application_secret) {
    $cookieName = 'fbs_' . $app_id;
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])) {
        return null;
    }
    $fb_session = array();
    //If magic_quotes is set then stripslashes else strip doublequotes then trim the cookie contents.
    //Parse the cookie - loading each parameter into an associative array $fb_session.
    parse_str(trim(get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($_COOKIE[$cookieName]): $_COOKIE[$cookieName],'"'), $fb_session);
    return $fb_session;
```

}

$fb_session['uid'] has the required data!

There is also a PHP SDK which creates an object containing this data:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

You can get UID using the getUser() method.....